# extract first image and removed the first image from string

Tags: image

I have a string that has both text and images but i would like to remove the first image only using php.

```
$string = 'This is my test <img src="link_to_image1">, some other text.
<img src="link_to_another_image" border="0">';
$str = preg_replace('/\<img src=\"[aA-zZ0-9\/\_\.]+\"\>/','',$string, 1);
```

Comment: i tried like this i got answer             $feed_desc = preg_replace('/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', '', $str,1);

Answer (score 0):

```
$feed_desc = preg_replace('/(<)([img])(\w+)([^>]*>)/', '', $str,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

to do it using a callback.  might be a little more flexible for you in case you're wanting to do stuff in the future based on images at different positions in the string

```
class imgReplacer {

    function cb($matches){

        if (!$this->counter){

            $this->counter++;
            return '';

        } else {

            return $matches[0];

        }

    }

}


$ir = new imgReplacer;
$ir->counter = 0;

$string = 'This is my test <img src="link_to_image1">, some other text. <img src="link_to_another_image" border="0">';

$string = preg_replace_callback(
    '#(<img.*?>)#',
    array(&$ir, 'cb'),
    $string);

echo $string;

This is my test , some other text. <img src="link_to_another_image" border="0">
```